# IE and Facebook signed request

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer

For some odd reason, i do not receive a "signed_request" when using IE.  If i use the same application in firefox/chrome i get the signed request!   has anyone had this problem and is there a solution.

I tried to search it up, but i can never get anything close to what i am asking (signed_request usually just takes over search and i get a bunch of documentation on how to parse it).

So i decided, well this is strange!

```
<?php print_r($_POST) // or request ?>
```

I made this as a page.  In FF and Chrome, both give me the post information, but IE does not give me anything... just

```
Array( )
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you accessing that page?  Using apps.facebook.com/appname/pagename or something else?

Answer (score 1):

signed request is the included for case where user access your content via facebook.  That should be signed to the server... and therefore it should not depends on the client browser.  check you code to see if you have done something like redirecting the request when the session / user is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that worked for me was to put this header in my tab page:

```
<?php
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
header('P3P: CP="HONK"');
?>
```

I've found this solution here: http://hasin.me/2011/09/30/story-about-blue-e-iframed-web-application-wastage-of-6-hours-and/